# Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables with joint probability density function

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous random variables with joint probability density function $f_{XY}(x,y)=K\cdot(x\cdot y+1)$ for $0≤x≤1$ and $0≤y≤x$, and $f_{XY}(x,y)=0$ otherwise. 
>   a) Prove that, since $f_{XY}(x,y)$ is a joint probability density function, $K$ equals $\frac{8}{5}$. 
>   b) Show that the marginal density function of $X$ is $f_X(x)=\frac{8}{5}\cdot(\frac{X^3}{2}+x)$ if $0≤x≤1$ and $f_X(x)=0$ otherwise. 
>   c) Use (b) to compute the distribution function of $X$. 
>   d) Compute $E[XY]$.

Solve: 
a) $F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}K\cdot(x\cdot y+1)dydx=1$ so $K=\frac{8}{5}$ What I compute is $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ or should I call it in onother way (maybe just $F(x,y)$)?

b) $f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{8}{5}\cdot(x\cdot y +1)dydx=\frac{8}{5}\cdot(\frac{x^3}{2} +x)$, same as above, what I compute is $f_{X}(x)$ or should I call it in onother way?

c) I don't know how to compute it, I think is the derivative of what I calculated in b.

d) I think that it is $E[XY]=\int_{0}^{x} x\cdot y \cdot  f(x,y) dy$ or $E[XY]=\int_{0}^{x} x\cdot y \cdot  f_x(x,y) dy$.

Is not clear for me what is the joint probability density function, marginal density function, distribution function in symbols, like the difference between $f$, $f_x$ and $F_X$ can someone please explain to me? And also can someone help me with this exercise. Thanks!

Comment: For c), integrate the result in b) from $0$ to $x$ which will give you the distribution function (cdf - $F_X(x)$). For d), integrate the first integral $(xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy)$ on the entire range $(0≤y≤x, 0≤x≤1)$.

Comment: thanks a lot man!